# Fetch (or Axios) in react native not working for expo for iOS apps

Tags: ios, react-native, fetch, expo

iOS doesn't allow to navigate to http only url, allowing only https.

There is a solution, which is changing some code inside info.plist file

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8717

How can I change settings for iOS, as it comes with only .expo folder but nothing else.

Do I need to change server configuration for this at last? :(

Answer (score 1):

As you properly find out, the problem is that iOS do not allow arbitrary calls to non-secure(http only) domains. It was a feature introduced with iOS 9 in order to push developers onto more secured connections.

As per writing of this(mid 2017), there is workaround. You should open

> {Your-project}/ios/{Your-project}/Info.plist

and set proper values for the domain you are targeting([docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33)).

Following example will disable ATS and allow HTTP call to `somedomain.com`:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>localhost</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

In your situation, I believe you are looking for the Info.plist file in the wrong place. It is not part of the node modules, instead look at the ios path specified above.

Comment: I know what i am looking for. But it seems I am looking for something that don't even exist. Expo project hide native files in their build and enviroment. So there is no place to search for info.plist

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Expo doesn't allow you to modify the App Transport Security Settings but may bake in a configuration option. [Here's a Github thread](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/406).

You can [`eject`](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/EJECTING.md#ejecting-to-regular-react-native) from Expo but only do this if you are 100% sure.

> This will give you a project very similar to one created by react-native init

This features an `ios` and `android` directory, navigating to `ios/YourProject/` will reveal `Info.plist`.

How much of a struggle would it be to install an SSL certificate on your server? It may be more beneficial to do this and you can use a free service like [letsencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).

Comment: No I really don't want to eject at this moment, but why is this a glitch, if using fetch is the basic requirement of a developer for both ios and android.
Most localhost servers are not ssl encrypted. This should have been added as it seems a general issue.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `fetch`, communication via https is something that is enforced by Apple. https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=12212016b

Comment: Yeah, I meant general communication methods like fetch or Axios. There should be a workout for this on temporary or localhost environment. :/

Comment: As you can see in this GH issue (https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/406#issuecomment-317612578), Expo DOES allow you to request resources from http:// urls by disabling the transport security. Therefore your issue is probably not related to ATS. If I had to guess what's going on, I'd say you are debugging on a device and trying to access a localhost service on your computer. If this is the case, you can fix it by making sure the phone and computer are on the same network, and binding your http server to your computer's public ip, or 0.0.0.0.

Comment: @jevakallio - That Github link is the same one posted in the answer. Using the same link, scroll up to the second comment. Furthermore, the comment you linked to states that Expo, by default, disables it. Two comments up states that right now (well 15 days ago), it's not possible to change it via configuration.

Comment: @Dan actually what the comment says is that they _disable_ ATS, which is to day they disable the mechanism that disables non-secure connections. Fetching HTTP resources in Expo works perfectly well, see for example https://snack.expo.io/Hk2jmtww-

Comment: See: https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/5b0db346d94822344529957b4827a3dbe949c1d1/ios/Exponent/Supporting/Info.plist#L71-L75

Comment: @Zafta see the comments above. Your issue is somewhere else, not in app transport security.